# SSRS: Toggle Report via a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm creating a single SSRS report that is composed of data drawn from different Datasets. What I'm wanting to do is have a drop down menu where the user selects the dataset they wish and have the appropriate table turn on and show them the dataset information.

Right now I'm testing with two tables and in there `Visibility` property I have the following expression:

```
=IIf(Parameters!AppSelection.Value = "STRAW", false, true)
```

The other table has the exact same line in the same place but with a different value between the quotes.

With my parameter, I created a new one and called it AppSelection and gave it 2 Available Values that matched the words between the quotes in my above expression. The data type for my parameter is `Text` and the Value of the each Available Value is left at null.

When I preview my report and select the different values in the parameter, nothing happens. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the null in the available values to your text, ie STRAW.
You may find that the tables show the other way round from expected, switch the true and false.